# Anyone around Good at both Javascript and Youtube api?, I am using lite-youtube js and I am confused in adding an eventlistener for onStateChange

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api, addeventlistener

I am new in studying and learning javascript and I am using a lite youtube js from paulirish from github
https://github.com/paulirish/lite-youtube-embed

I want to get onstatechange and addeventlistener after the video ends.
I found some codes here in stackoverflow about the same problem, I tried their codes but it doesn't seem to work because lite-youtube is a bit different in youtube api's coding. I am confused in how to make this work and get onStateChange to add an eventlistener.

I have tried to make my own modification in his javascript but I don't have the knowledge and experience in using both js and youtube api. I have been trying to get the onstate value with onStateChange player.getPlayerState() with my own codes but I fail:

```
async function getPlayerState(number, id) { let num = document.querySelector(lite-youtube[id='${id}']`);
let player = await num.getYTPlayer();
player?.getPlayerState(number, true);
}

playlist.addEventListener('click', () => {
this.getPlayerState(1, '1') // the string inside works and plays the specific video id but it does not get the PlayerState value
if (this.getPlayerState(0, '1')) {
this.getPlayerState(1, '2') //<=this always trigger the specific video id but it plays no matter what is changed on the ifcondition
}
});
```

The link to Youtube api I am saying is here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getPlayerState

Thank You Very Much in Advance to Anyone who will be able to Help!

Comment: I recommend using the official Google API js client library instead of third party libraries if you want to use that then you may have better luck posting questions on their issue forum