How to scroll every 4 div specifically, with side scrolling buttons?
How to scroll every 4 div specifically, with side scrolling buttons?
On a previous question I asked about how to loop and simplify codes of multiple side scrolling buttons in every overflow-x: How to loop and simplify code of multiple side scrolling buttons that scrolls specific row in javascript?
Now with this answered by Elna Haim, I am asking for help, to anyone knowledgeable in javascript on how is it possible to scroll every 4 div specifically and specifically stops and fits the 4 boxes in it when next and back button is clicked.
It can scroll using data-scroll="1280" but every time the screen size changes the scrolling gets broken too, and you will be able to see the div getting cut in half on the code below.
Also there's a problem in the margin not triggering in the code snippet, I don't know why.


const nextbtns = document.querySelectorAll('.next')
const backbtns = document.querySelectorAll('.back')

for (let nxt of nextbtns) {
    nxt.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const con = nxt.getAttribute("data-con");
      const target = nxt.getAttribute("data-scroll");
      document.querySelector(`#${con}`).scrollLeft += parseInt(target, 10);
    });
}

for (let bck of backbtns) {
    bck.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const con = bck.getAttribute("data-con");
      const target = bck.getAttribute("data-scroll");
      document.querySelector(`#${con}`).scrollLeft -= parseInt(target, 10);
    });
}
.row {
width: 100%;
height: 270px;
overflow-x: hidden;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
scrollbar-width: none;
}
.container {
overflow-x: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
scrollbar-width: none;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
transition: scroll-behavior .5s ease-in-out;
}
.box {
width: 24%;
height: 180px;
background-color: #171717;
border-radius: 20px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 14;
}

.btns button {
--color: #202020;
background-color: #202020;
padding: 8px 17.5px 12px 17.5px;
border: 3px solid var(--color);
color: grey;
border-radius: 50px;
font-family: 'Arial Black';
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
}
<html>
  <body>
<div class="row">
  <a class="btns">
    <button type="button" class="back" data-con="con" data-scroll="1321">&#8249</button>
    <button type="button" class="next" data-con="con" data-scroll="1321">&#8250</button>
  </a>
  <div class="container" id="con">
    <center>
      <div class="box">
      </div><div class="box">
      </div><div class="box">
      </div><div class="box">
      </div><div class="box">
      </div><div class="box">
      </div><div class="box">
      </div><div class="box">
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>



For the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c0f9da82/
The margin is still not working I guess it would only work if codes are saved locally.
Thanks Alot to Elna Haim for answering the previous question and is looking to answer this question again! If anyone else can help answer the question it would be Greatly appreciated!
Also I have another question in: Anyone around Good at both Javascript and Youtube api?, I am using lite-youtube js and I am confused in adding an eventlistener for onStateChange Where I am using lite youtube js by paulirish on github, and asked how is it possible to create an event listener to get the onStateChange end parameter. Thank you very much in advance! to everyone looking to answer my questions!

Hi, best not to ask two questions in one post.

Is there ag reason your margin value doesn't have a unit (eg px)?

Yes thank you, I forgot both of it,  I copied this Question and deleted the other one and forgot to link it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78229659/anyone-around-good-at-both-javascript-and-youtube-api-i-am-using-lite-youtube

@Frost here is another example how you can achieve it. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-payne-kmlzvm i will post it as an answer with a detailed explanation later.

One way to achieve it, is to convert your code to work as a mini library. and to make sure you are handling each row separtly (common way to work with sliders / swipers).
in order to achieve it we need to modify the code a little:
HTML:
each row will be a "stand alone component", and now it will look like this:
Very important each row must have a unique id and each container must have the default page attribute (this will define the page we show by default).
*notice we need unique id in the row and in the container
<div class="row" id="uniqueRowId">
  <a class="btns">
    <button type="button" class="back" >&#8249</button>
    <button type="button" class="next" >&#8250</button>
  </a>
  <div class="container" id="container1" page="0">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2 </div>
      <div class="box">3 </div>
      <div class="box">4 </div>
      <div class="box">5 </div>
      <div class="box">6 </div>
      <div class="box">7 </div>
      <div class="box">8 </div>
      <div class="box">9 </div>
      <div class="box">10 </div>
      <div class="box">11 </div>
      <div class="box">12 </div>
      <div class="box">13 </div>
      <div class="box">14 </div>
      <div class="box">15 </div>
      <div class="box">16 </div>
  </div>
</div>

the css also need to be improved, we will use display flex, and gap in the container. and on the box we will apply min-width:
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
.container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  transition: scroll-behavior 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 14px;
}
.box {
  min-width: calc(25% - 14px);
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #171717;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.btns button {
  --color: #202020;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 8px 17.5px 12px 17.5px;
  border: 3px solid var(--color);
  color: grey;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-family: "Arial Black";
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


And now the js. its a bit different from what you have currently, but i built it on top of the exist code.
// defaults.
const BOXES_PER_VIEW = 4;
const SPACE_BETWEEN = 14;

// handler to change page (action will represnt +1 or -1).
const handlePageChange = (container, action) => {
  const page = parseInt(container.getAttribute("page"), 10);
  container.setAttribute("page", page + action);

  return page + action;
};

// getting the current page from the container.
const getCurrentPage = (container) => {
  const page = container.getAttribute("page");
  return parseInt(page, 10);
};

const init = (isResizing, { nextbtns, backbtns, containerInit, boxes }) => {
  const container = document.getElementById(containerInit.id);
  const pages = Math.floor(container.childElementCount / BOXES_PER_VIEW);

  let boxSize = container.clientWidth / BOXES_PER_VIEW - SPACE_BETWEEN;

  for (let box of boxes) {
    box.style.minWidth = `${boxSize}px`;
  }

  if (isResizing) {
    container.scrollLeft = container.clientWidth * getCurrentPage(container);
  }
  if (!isResizing) {
    for (let nxt of nextbtns) {
      nxt.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (getCurrentPage(container) < pages) {
          handlePageChange(container, +1);

          container.scrollLeft += container.clientWidth;
        }
      });
    }

    for (let bck of backbtns) {
      bck.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (getCurrentPage(container) > 0) {
          handlePageChange(container, -1);

          container.scrollLeft -= container.clientWidth;
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

function createRowSlider(row) {
  const nextbtns = row.querySelectorAll(".next");
  const backbtns = row.querySelectorAll(".back");
  const containerInit = row.querySelector(".container");
  const boxes = row.querySelectorAll(".box");
  init(false, { nextbtns, backbtns, containerInit, boxes });
  window.addEventListener("resize", () =>
    init(true, { nextbtns, backbtns, containerInit, boxes })
  );
}

// unique rows
const uniqueRow = document.getElementById("uniqueRowId");
const uniqueRow2 = document.getElementById("uniqueRowId2");
// creating the row sliders
createRowSlider(uniqueRow);
createRowSlider(uniqueRow2);


here is a working codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-payne-kmlzvm
**NOTE: we dont implement any lazy load here. means the browser will load all the rows and all the content at once. might be bad for performace. you need to take it into concideration.
This is a basic implementation of slider library, you can develop it more for your needs.

I did some small changes in codesandbox. feel free to fork it and play with the code, to get your desire result.

Wow! that's a very specific and mind boggling code! thank you very much for the effort in answering!

@Frost im glad it helped. Let me know if you need further explanation or help.

Instead of scroll, you can replace the visible cards with next 4 cards. I have set different color to each card so you can see it in action. Basically, I am storing all the cards in an array, and appending 4 cards at a time according to the pressed button.


const nextbtn = document.querySelector('.next')
const backbtn = document.querySelector('.back')
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
const container = document.getElementById('con');

let tempr = [];
let a = 0;
let b = 4;
let autoS;
//number of cards to show
nCards = 4;

function nextAnim() {
  tempr.slice(a, b).forEach((d) => {
    if (typeof(d) == 'object') {
      d.style.animation = "append-animate2 1s";
      //a.addEventListener("animationend", );
      container.appendChild(d);
    }
  })
}

function nextFour() {
  if (b >= tempr.length) {
    a = 0;
    b = 4;
  } else {
    a = a + 4;
    b = b + 4;
  }
  [...container.children].forEach((a) => {
    a.style.animation = "append-animate .6s";
    setTimeout(() => a.remove(), 500)
  });
  setTimeout(() => nextAnim(), 400)
}

function prevFour() {
  if (a <= 0) return;
  a = a - 4;
  b = b - 4;
  [...container.children].forEach((a) => {
    a.style.animation = "append-animate .6s";
    setTimeout(() => a.remove(), 500)
  });
  setTimeout(() => nextAnim(), 400)
}

//Store all cards in an Array

[...box].forEach((a) => {
  tempr.push(a);
  a.remove()
});

//First four cards on render
function initial() {
  tempr.slice(a, b).forEach((a) => {
    a.style.animation = "append-animate2 .5s 1";
    container.appendChild(a)
  });
}

initial();

nextbtn.addEventListener("click", nextFour)

backbtn.addEventListener("click", prevFour)

//Infinite auto scroll
function autoScroll() {
  autoS = setInterval(() => {
    if (b >= tempr.length) {
      a = 0;
      b = 4;
      setTimeout(() => initial(), 500);
      [...box].forEach((a) => {
        a.style.animation = "append-animate .6s";
        setTimeout(() => a.remove(), 500)
      });
      return;
    }
    nextFour()

  }, 2500)
}

function autoScr() {
  autoScroll();
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(autoS);
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  transition: scroll-behavior 1s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  left: 20;
  right: 10;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 180px;
  background-color: #171717;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 14;
}

.btns button {
  position: fixed;
  --color: #202020;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 8px 17.5px 12px 17.5px;
  border: 3px solid var(--color);
  color: grey;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes append-animate {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-400%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes append-animate2 {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#auto {
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.btnCon {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btnCon2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btnCon button {
  color: white;
}

.btnCon2 button {
  color: white;
}
<div class="row">
  <a class="btns">
    <div class="btnCon">
      <button type="button" class="back" data-con="con" data-scroll="1321">&#8249</button>
      <button type="button" class="next" data-con="con" data-scroll="1321">&#8250</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btnCon2">
      <button type="button" onClick='autoScr()' id="auto" data-con="con" data-scroll="1321">Autoscroll</button>
      <button type="button" onClick='stop()' id="auto" data-con="con" data-scroll="1321">Stop</button>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="container" id="con">

    <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: yellow;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: black;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: green;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: lightblue;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: gray;">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>




Thank you very much for the helpful answer and for the code!

Thank you for your code!, The plan for the website I am creating for the future is to build autoplay, but it seems the store and appendchild technique can hinder the autoplay function. You can visit it at http://streamnc.us.to

@Frost It is possible through setInterval() function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

I see Thank you!, I tried adding animation: https://jsfiddle.net/9qukp6m8/2/ and I have tried looping the code  with the codes you have given. but it seems that the boxes from different rows mix together and move from different rows (or it just disappears), do you know any possible fix for this? https://jsfiddle.net/9qukp6m8/1/

I'm sorry for asking too many questions, I am a javascript newbie

@Frost No worries friend. The site is for asking questions.

@Frost Sorry I forgot to update you on it. You should animate elements using Keyframes rather than pure Javascript. It is easier and gives so much space to experiment. I have updated the answer with animations, run the snippet to check it out. also, I have added infinite auto-scroll. Click the Autoscroll button to start it. You are already familiar with the code, so it will be easy to understand. (The code is bit longer now, because it does everything) Here is the jsfiddle-> https://jsfiddle.net/Akshyap/pLzncsv4/7/
